# Database of programming terms

Tags: data-request, programming, english

I want to find a [terminology database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Termbase) with programming terms , for example:

- Front-end
- UI/UX
- ruby
- RoR
- HTML 5
- HTML

Any idea ?

Comment: Are you looking for a data(base) design, or an existing data source?

Comment: @philshem existing data source .Problem that i need a lot of programming terms and I wont  to write it by myself , because they are more than 500+

Comment: I think you'll need to improve the question to better indicate what you are looking for.

Comment: http://theswo.sourceforge.net/ ?

Comment: Do you need abbreviations or full names? Or both?

Comment: @nicolasraoul any u can find, doesnt matter

Comment: @nlpkr: Is it in the context of Human Resources / Recruitment? For instance [FileSystemWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) is a programming term but is maybe more deeply technical than you want?